# "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." Google Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
import Login from "./components/login";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    function start() {
      gapi.client.init({
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: [
          "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest",
        ],
        scope:
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics",
      });
    }

    gapi.load("client:auth2", start);
  }, []);

  const callApi = () => {
    gapi.client.load("analyticsreporting", "v4", () => {
      // Prepare the request
      const accessToken = gapi.client.getToken().access_token;

      const batchRequest = {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: process.env.REACT_APP_VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: "7daysAgo",
                endDate: "today",
              },
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: "ga:sessions",
              },
            ],
            dimensions: [
              {
                name: "ga:date",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };

      // Make the request
      gapi.client.analyticsreporting.reports
        .batchGet({
          resource: batchRequest,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // Add the access token to the header
          },
        })
        .then((response: any) => {
          const reports = response.result.reports;
          console.log(reports);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error("Error fetching analytics data:", error.result.error);
        });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Login />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);
        }}
      >
        Log token
      </button>
      <button onClick={callApi}>Call Api</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I cant figure out why this does not work, i appreciate any help, i try to fetch some data from the Google Analytics Reporting Api, I'm new to google Apis but i need to make this app and figure it out.

The access token is valid and works, but i get the error "Request had insufficient authentification scopes".

Comment: Where did the access token come from

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo react-google-login

Comment: but signin isnt oauth2 is it even prompting you to consent?

Comment: Have you tried checking the javscript sample.  unfortunately i know very little about react https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js